# How to satisfy "media/message-store" API call requirement in the RingCentral app graduation process?

Tags: ringcentral, ringcentral-webhooks

I am in the procedure of Production Graduation Requirements in the RingCentral for my application.

My app passed all required API calls except one: "media/message-store".
and I am not sure what is it?
and how it differs from resources under "extension/message-store" which is passed.

While doing API overview I don't see a section like "media/message-store".

I am writing here because the RingCentral forum is in the read-only mode since yesterday.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @arecaps: contact with the RingCentral support helped me. They activated my app.